# Git commit in PhpStorm 2023.1 opens diff, not file

Tags: phpstorm

When you open the git commit widget, and double click on a file, it doesn't open the file itself, rather it opens the diff.

Is there a way to change the behaviour, so it opens the actual file?

If theres no way to do this.. is there a way to simply view all the files currently changed?

Comment: Do you have a settings (cog icon) there? Show a screenshot of what that menu has.

Comment: *"is there a way to simply view all the files currently changed?"* What about "All Changed Files" scope in the Project View panel? Will that do any good? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-tool-window.html#views